# About WIFI device

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

In my office i am using NETGEAR Wi-Fi device. Some person get my wifi password and using my internet connection. I am using NETGEAR genie software. it shows the connected device MAC address & IP address. Then how to block the particular device. (IP address) I have many time change my wifi password. that also no use.
    My PC have wired connection with WIFI system. I cant turnoff myWIFI. Bcse my boss using Laptop. i only want to block the particular device IP. Kindly send the solution. My PC OS is win 7 home premium 64bit. my wifi system is NETGEAR-WNR3500Lv2

Comment: What sort of encryption are you using WPA, WPA2, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

in the router configuration, you should have a mac-filtering option.
add the mac-address of the user you want to block in the "blocked" section.

edit: the user can change his/her mac adress and reconnect, so you're better off with a stronger protection of the network...

(and change the type of key you're using, since it's so easily found each time, WEP key ?)